# SuperCollider access sample rate in a synthdef

Tags: supercollider

how to find/get the samplerate number that SuperCollider is running into a patch as a variable?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [SampleRate.ir](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/SampleRate.html) ugen, which always returns the current sample rate.

Note that using `s.sampleRate` is not the best answer - it gets you the sample rate at the time the [synthdef](http://doc.sccode.org/Classes/SynthDef.html) is compiled, not the sample rate at the time the synth is running...